# $21 x^2 - 21 px + 49p - 7 = 0$ has two non integer roots a and b, where a,b $>=1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

What is the value of a + b?

I ve worked with $a*b$ which is $\frac{49p-7}{21}$ but couldn't proceed.
Actually, it is a multiple choice with the following options:

$\frac{59}3, \frac{60}3, \frac{61}3, \frac{62}3,$ or $\frac{63}3$

Comment: What are a and b?

Comment: When you look at the formula to solve the roots, it's fairly easy to figure out what the sum of the roots is.

Comment: @gimusi the non-integer roots, I suppose

Comment: Very similar to how you can work out $ab$, you can also work out $a+b$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Oh yes of course!

Comment: @Wawar Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

We have that

- $a+b = p$
- $ab=(49p-7)/21$

then look for the integer solution to that system that is

- $49p-7\equiv 0 \mod{21}$

Comment: Why should looking for the integer solution, for 1,2, and 3, they give respectively 28/49, 1, and 70/49?

Comment: @Wawar $a,b \in \Bbb{Z} \implies ab \in \Bbb{Z}$